# Hibernate Connection count in spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I had one working spring mvc (4.2.5.RELEASE) application using hibernate (4.3.11.Final)

Now we are facing the issue that connection count on the database side is getting full frequently.

I had tried to print the connection stats at the time of getting the hibernate session like

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Statistics stat = sessionFactory.getStatistics();
        stat.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
        System.out.println("connection open count"+ stat.getCollectionFetchCount() +"Session open count"+ stat.getSessionOpenCount()+"Session Close count"+ stat.getSessionCloseCount()+"stat.getQueryCacheMissCount(): "+stat.getQueryCacheMissCount());
        //logger.debug("hibernate session parameters connection count=>"+stat.getConnectCount()+"session open count==>"+stat.getSessionOpenCount());
```

While execution i got the following logs

```
hibernate session parameters connection count=>139591 session open count==>139590
```

Now, i got the conclusion from team members that above log  represents  the number of times Hibernate asked for a connection, and not the number of connections occurred by database

So, i didn't know how to solve the this issue.

Also, I enable the second level cache in the hibernate configuration

```
properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" );
```